# ALE Spaces as Spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, string-theory, gauge-theory

I asked the following question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263654/instanton-moduli-space-on-ale-spaces/263816#263816) on MathOverflow, with regards to instanton moduli spaces on certain ALE manifolds.  *In particular, for the time being, I'm only interested in the $A_{N-1}$ resolutions of $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{N}$*.  Within the phenomenal answer to my question above, it was pointed out that in physics, there are two entirely different situations: you can consider an ALE space to be part of the internal six dimensional space in string theory, *or* in some cases you actually want the ALE space to be the four-dimensional spacetime itself.

I've more or less made peace with the first case.  The details are above me, but I think you talk about having these blown-up exceptional divisors as part of your ALE space, and considering branes wrapping these 2-cycles correspond to BPS particles in the spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.  Hence, we get a beautiful relationship between instanton counting on $\mathbb{R}^{4} = \mathbb{C}^{2}$ and a topological string theory on some threefold such that four of the six real dimensions are an ALE space!

I was hoping someone could explain to this poor mathematician what motivation the second case has: in other words, why would physicists want to take an ALE space as the four dimensional spacetime?  I'm guessing the answer might include the words Taub-NUT or Eguchi-Hanson in the context of General Relativity, but I'm not sure.  In addition, what is the corresponding topological string theory, if any?  i.e. what string theory engineers a SUSY gauge theory on this ALE space.  Or maybe I'm just totally confused about how all this works.